# Mistaked code after execute a job using tPigLoad, tPigMap and tPigStoreResult

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, cloudera-cdh

I created my first project with Talend Open studio 6.3.0 with Cloudera CDH5.8.
I followed this tutorial
[tuto Talend6.3.0](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataGettingStartedGuide63EN/5.1.5+Writing+the+output+to+HDFS)
and now i arrived to the end.
I created a job for load, make join and display the result.
At the end , when I execute my job, i receive some error line (as mentioned in picture) [error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhbyI.png).
So , now what i must do for resolve this.
I hope receive your help, i'm blocked here.
Thank you very much.